# How to Count Enum Across Table MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, enums

I have a table `studentexamrecord`

```
Name|Module1|Module2|Module3|Total
A-------RT-----PASS---PASS 
B-------RC-----RC------RT
C-------RT-----PASS----RC
```

I would like to calculate the total number of column that contains RT and RC at the total column.

What should i do?

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: my expected output is number (integer) ? what if the column contains RT2 RT3, but i need function that at total it count all column than contains word RT

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This query returns the sum of total in record that contain `module1 = RC` edit it to much you condition :

```
Select  
    sum(if(module1 = RT, total, 0)) 
from 
    studentexamrecord;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give it a try:

```
SELECT 
Name,
Module1,
Module2,
Module3,
(
(Module1 = 'RT' OR Module1 = 'RC')+
(Module2 = 'RT' OR Module2 = 'RC')+
(Module3 = 'RT' OR Module3 = 'RC')
) AS Total
FROM your_table
```

**Note:** MySQL boolean expression resolves into `0/1`. Let's say if `Module1` is `RC` or `RT` then the following expression returns `1`

`(Module1 = 'RT' OR Module1 = 'RC') returns 1`

otherwise it returns zero (`0`)